# How can I skip reading from a connected client in C?

Tags: c, networking, pthreads

I am working on a TCP client server application with threads where clients take turns messaging the server(similar to a turn based game).
The server sends a message to the client but the client has **n** seconds to respond. If the client doesn't respond in time the server should go to the next client without closing the connection. Is there a way to skip the **read()** call from the server?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think the client needs to skip the read? It's difficult to say anything for sure with such a brief description. But generally the client would just do whatever it needs to do and the server will handle the timeout independently.

Comment: As a general rule, when consuming data from a non-seekable file, such as a socket, one must read each byte in order to read any subsequent bytes.  What, if anything, you *do* with what you've read is at your discretion, but no, you cannot skip reads from such data sources in the sense you seem to mean.

Comment: The best way to *skip the read call* is to use non-blocking reads. And do the bookkeeping.

Comment: @wildplasser, I don't see how non-blocking reads provide for *skipping* read calls in any sense relevant to the question.  Avoiding blocking doesn't skip the read, nor does it even in itself provide for a timeout.

Comment: I need the server to skip reading from the client if the client didn't respond in time. All the client does is get a message and respond to it, and if it's late or didn't answer at all the server should move on to other clients.

Comment: From the (badly phrased) problem definition, it is clear (at least: to me) that he does not want to block in a read() call.

Comment: That's not so clear to me, @wildplasser.  I'd say that they don't want to block *indefinitely* in a `read()` call, but they expressly do want to allow the client a certain amount of time to respond.  Simply performing a non-blocking read does not address that.

Comment: Reading from a socket when there is nothing to read will block *indefinitely*. (the read() cannot return zero, because that would mean EOF, which it is not) Select() and poll() will *almost* work without non-blocking sockets (in practice: they won't)

Comment: So, @wildplasser, a viable answer would then be "use `select()` or `poll()`" (I agree).  Maybe non-blocking reads are an implementation detail attending that, but they do not themselves achieve what the OP is after, neither literally nor in the sense the OP seems to mean.

Comment: @lucimaster Your description made it sound like you want to skip the read from the client side.  But your last comment made it clearer that it is the server side read you want to skip. In that case `select` with a timeout will do it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Unfortunately, he also thinks he needs threads, which only makes the problem **more** difficult.

Comment: I use threads to handle each client individually with ticket locks for synchronization so each thread will work with only one client

Comment: So, now you'll have to juggle threads and locks, too. And suffer from leak or starvation. (in a non-threaded server, only file descriptors and memory are leakable resources)

Comment: I think by "skip" he means "give up on;" if so, there are a few options, the most straightforward would be to set a time limit for the read to finish, and error check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you mean about the server skipping `read()` calls, but I think you're talking about implementing the response timeout you describe.  A common way to do that would be to engage the `select()` function, which allows you to wait for up to a specified amount of time for a file descriptor to become ready.  You would then choose whether to `read()` or to move on to the next client based on whether `select()` signals that the wanted file descriptor is ready.

Very roughly, that might be something along these lines:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

// ...

    fd_set read_fds;

    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    FD_SET(client_fd, &read_fds);

    struct timeval timeout = { .tv_sec = 5, .tv_usec = 0 };

    int num_ready = select(client_fd + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

    if (num_ready == -1) {
        // handle error ...
    } else if (num_ready == 0) {
        // handle timeout ...
    } else if (num_ready == 1) {
        // handle client response ...
    } else {
        // should not happen
        assert(0);
    }
```

You could also consider alternatives to `select()` with similar behavior, such as `poll()` and `epoll_wait()`.  Also, you will probably find it advantageous in connection with this to configure the client sockets for non-blocking I/O, though this is not a technical requirement for use of the `select()`, *etc*. functions.

Do note that it's more complicated than that, however.  There are at least these additional considerations:

- You will need to be prepared for cases where the client disconnects.
- if a client's response arrives too late then you will need to read that response and (presumably) discard it before you can handle any subsequent response from the same client.
- Responses might be split into multiple pieces on the wire, so the beginning of a response might arrive within the timeout, yet the end not, and maybe not at all.
- For robustness, you'll need to handle cases where the wait is interrupted by a signal prior to time expiring.  Presumably you would want in that case to resume waiting, but not restart the timeout.